# Help--short story where high ranking humans are given the privilege of working

Tags: story-identification

I thought this was called *The Midas Touch*, and I thought it was by Thomas Disch.  But I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: I think this isn't the right title, since neither of the [two](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?957043) [stories](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1025504) by this name ring a bell to me, whereas I'm pretty sure I've read this story. Now if I could only remember where.

Comment: Duplicate of [Story about a future of over-production](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/6641/231).

Comment: If you don't mind my asking, Margot, did you search on SciFi.SE before posting this question (which is good on it's own merits, by the way)? The reason I ask is because one of [Jeff's complaints about *-identification questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/02/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) is that they don't help the next person with the question (because everyone recalls a different set of trivia) and that may be the case here.

Comment: This is a common theme in many science fiction stories up through the 1970s. I'm not sure this is answerable unless more information is given.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably thinking of "The Midas Plague" and its sequels, by [Frederik Pohl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frederik_Pohl), collected in [*Midas World*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midas_World).