# Science Fiction Novel depicting a society where people are paid to shop and pay to work

Tags: story-identification, novel

I am looking for the author and title for a Science Fiction novel depicting a society where people are paid to obtain necessities and pay to work. It may be a Heinlein, Asimov, or Clark title. Does anyone remember that subplot?

Comment: This sounds pretty broad; do you remember any other details? Anything about the setting or characters? When you read it?

Comment: I don't know about the paid to work bit, but James Womak's *Terraplane* envisions a Late USSR wherein people were coerced to shop.

Comment: Fairly highly duplicated: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=Midas+Plague

Comment: Reopened. There's no acceptance from the OP.

Answer (score 8):

Not an exact match, but the topsy-turvy nature is reminiscent of Frederik Pohl's [The Midas Plague](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?45770) which is set in a society in which robotic production has created such an avalanche of consumer goods that the 'poor' are forced to work many hours a day to use up their ration of luxuries.  The 'rich' live relatively austere lives.

It was later expanded into a novel called [Midas World](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?29636)

[image]

Comment: That makes no sense

Comment: Can no one find the off switch for the commodity creating machines?

Comment: @S.Fruggiero - If you read the book, you can a) Find out and B) Let us know :-)

Comment: @Richard I read the [book](https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1954-04/Galaxy_1954_04#page/n7/mode/2up) and can report that the belief is that if no one is consuming luxuries, then the need for inovation and discovery of better luxuries is lost. So people must consume 'x' amount of things so that more can be created. Its a very odd idea to be sure. I also don't think they heard of recycling.

Comment: It's also partially tied to that society was on the brink of riots at the time when the robots were set to automatically produce. No one wants to mess with what is working.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero - Cheers. An interesting concept. I shall definitely be adding this one to my "to read" list.

Comment: I suggest reading the short version, IMHO it is even harder to suspend disbelief at novel length.

Comment: No, it doesn't make much sense, and a lot of people said so at the time. However, Pohl was writing a satire of capitalism, not a Heinleinian prediction.

The means of production, distribution and exchange have been turned over to robots, programmed simply to increase output. The idea that society should work towards human happiness and fulfilment has been lost.
Eventually the hero finds the obvious capitalist solution - the robots consume the goods which they produce, thus completing the supply-and-demand circle (and removing any potential revolutionary threat to the system).

Comment: See the classic "autofac" by Phillip k dick for another take on the problem of overzealous mechanized production. https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1955-11/Galaxy_1955_11#page/n71/mode/2up

Comment: The novel has two, not one problem points. First, of course, is the determination of the society to keep the production lines cranked up. Pohl tries to justify it, but frankly it sounds pretty lame, and Pohl skipped over the issue as quickly as he could. Second, how do you force people to over-consume (if they are poor)? Put them in jail where they are force-fed? In this respect, "Midas World" seems to be an unintentional satire on the conformist society of the 50s. Jail time is constant threat to one of the characters, but it's never made explicit how such incarceration would work.

Answer (score 3):

The part where people are paid for buying but pay to work sounds like Lloyd Biggle's Round Trip To Esidarap, where a couple from our world take a trip to 'Kroywen' offered by a competing travel agency in their town. When they buy items they are paid in 'Rallods'.

The isfdb entry is here https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?72632

It is available to read on Google books