# Title and author of short sf-story on overcrowded society with obligatory consumption quota

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

The story is about a family living in a flat with extreme low ceiling to cram as many people as possible in a building and due to that the building material is trash. It is not possible to stand upright. Each person has to acquire a specific quota consumption goods each day to keep the economy balanced. Work is minimal and consists of overseeing automated production. Going for a day on the beach you have to drive through a tunnel. To "cull" population sometimes a lane in the tunnel is closed of and filled with cyanide.

It was written originally in English but I read it in Swedish translation around 1960.

Comment: I remember this being answered here

Comment: @Gallifreyan We have a [policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7065/31394) not to close story-ID questions as dupes until the answer has been confirmed correct by the OP.

Comment: [60s short story, robot cars travel through a tunnel, occupants are liquefied](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/141480/60s-short-story-robot-cars-travel-through-a-tunnel-occupants-are-liquefied/141483)

Comment: @Randal'Thor _"patience, my young padawan"_ would be appropriate here :) I was hasty. __Max__, could your story be _The Tunnel Ahead_?

Comment: @Gallifreyan - [Closing Story-Ident questions as duplicates (where there's no acceptance)](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7065/closing-story-ident-questions-as-duplicates-where-theres-no-acceptance) - Required (policy) reading...

Comment: You might be conflating this story with [The Midas Plague](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84659/science-fiction-novel-depicting-a-society-where-people-are-paid-to-shop-and-pay)

Comment: As Valorum says, the story about the consumption quotas is The Midas Plague, but that doesn't have anything about low ceilings or bad construction; on the contrary, "poor" people live in extremely opulent surroundings.

Comment: The cyanide tunnel story can be found on Google by looking for *how long it was supposed to take for the giant fans to blow the cyanide gas away* (or the election slogan "Depopulation without Discrimination"). Unfortunately, my google-fu is not enough to get the title, but I read it once and it *is* the same story.

Comment: A modest proposal: There is always a simple solution to both the problem of overpopulation and insufficient resources, Soylent Green.

Comment: @RichS - It's People-icious!