# Short Story About Consumerism

Tags: story-identification

In this story, we are introduced to a couple that is "poor" (i.e. not rich). The story goes on for a bit.

At the end of the story, we realize that being poor means that they are required to buy and consume material goods. Rich people are not required to do so.

This has been bugging me for quite a while. I read it back in the 80's or 90's, out of a library book.

Comment: Are you certain it was Asimov? I've read most of what he's written, and this doesn't ring a bell. But of course, "most" is not "all".

Comment: The story exists, but I'm pretty sure it's not *by* Asimov; It may have been in a collection that had the good doctor's name on it though.

Comment: Not Asimov. Pohl. "The Midas Plague" and we've got [questions on it already](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21916/help-short-story-where-high-ranking-humans-are-given-the-privilege-of-working). Ah ... [here's the master](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6641/story-about-a-future-of-over-production).

Comment: Ah, thank you! I'm reading the linked page on the other question, and I think that *is* it. No wonder I couldn't find the Asimov short story.