# Searching for title about consumption

Tags: story-identification

What is the story in which the male protagonist has to keep consuming, using things up, while his higher status father-in-law is able to simply work in his garden?

Comment: What in particular about this story makes it sci-fi / fantasy? More details would be helpful, as well as ensuring that it is not off-topic for this SE site

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Story about a future of over-production](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6641/story-about-a-future-of-over-production)

Answer (score 9):

[The Midas Plague](https://archive.org/stream/galaxymagazine-1954-04/Galaxy_1954_04#page/n7/mode/2up) by Frederik Pohl, published in [Midas World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midas_World), according to wikipedia:

> "The Midas Plague" (originally published in Galaxy in 1954). In a
>   world of cheap energy, robots are overproducing the commodities
>   enjoyed by mankind. The lower-class "poor" must spend their lives in
>   frantic consumption, trying to keep up with the robots' extravagant 
>   production, while the upper-class "rich" can live lives of simplicity. Property crime is
>   nonexistent, and the government Ration Board enforces the use of
>   ration stamps to ensure that everyone consumes their quotas. The story
>   deals with Morey Fry, who marries a woman from a higher-class family.
>   Raised in a home with only five rooms she is unused to a life of
>   forced consumption in their mansion of 26 rooms, nine automobiles, and
>   five robots, causing arguments. Trained as an engineer, Morey modifies
>   his robots to enjoy helping to consume his family's quota. He fears
>   punishment when his idea is discovered, but the Ration Board—which has
>   been looking for a way to abolish itself—quickly implements Morey's
>   idea across the world.